# Credit Card Expiry Date Validation

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to validate the expiry date of credit card entered by the user. Ex.12/2019
Also try to make sure user enter valid month (1-12) and valid year (> 2018 ).

The following is my code so far I have worked on and so far it is not working.

Can you see what is wrong with my code and what is the best way to achieve my goal of expiry date validation?

HTML:

```
    <input name="exp_date" id="exp_date" type="text" maxlength="7" onChange="validateExp()" placeholder="MM / YYYY ">
      <br>
        <span id="error4" ></span>
      <br>
```

JS:

```
    function validateExp(){
    var expire = document.getElementById("exp_date");
    var d = new Date();
      var currentYear = d.getFullYear();
      var currentMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
      // get parts of the expiration date
      var parts = expire.toString().split(/[-\/]+/);
      var year = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
      var month = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
      // compare the dates
      if (year < currentYear || (year == currentYear && month < currentMonth)) {
        error4.innerHTML = "The expiry date has passed.\n";

      }else if (month > 12){
       error4.innerHTML = "Invalid month.\n";
      };
    };
```

Comment: This line seems faulty: 
var parts = expire.toString().split(/[-\/]+/);
Here it should be 
var parts = expire.value.split(/[-\/]+/);

Comment: Shall we assume, `<input>` attribute `type="date"` is not suitable, for some reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check credit card expiration date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72658732/how-to-check-credit-card-expiration-date)